# LaTeX formats the equation wrong and doesnt show the whole equation in the output

Tags: equations, align

[image: It looks like this]

This is how it looks like in LaTeX. And it should be looking like the handwriting here: [image: Handwriting]

I need the explanation with the down pointed brace, because these are complex numbers and hard to understand, when i look before the exam on it. But unfortunately, with \begin{equation*} etc. alone i cant make the "=" and so on not among themselves. I need here the align. But for the underbraces i need the \begin{equation*} etc. So I dont know how to manage this mess. Hope i get a quick answer :s This is the code:

```
\begin{align*}
        \Vec{a}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix*} \in \mathbb{C}^2\\
        \bar{\Vec{a}}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] \bar{a}_1\\ \bar{a}_2 \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \Vec{a}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 1-2i\\1+2i \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \bar{\Vec{a}}&= \begin{pmatrix*} 1+2i\\1-2i \end{pmatrix*}\\
        (\bar{\Vec{a}})^T &= (a+2i;1-2i)\\
        \Vec{b}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] i\\-i \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \langle \Vec{a},\Vec{b} \rangle &= (1+2i;1-2i) \cdot \begin{pmatrix*}[r] i\\-i \end{pmatrix*}\\
        &=  \begin{equation*}
            \underbrace{(1+2i}_{\substack{a_1}}\underbrace{i}_{\substack{b_1}}+ \underbrace{(1-2i)}_{\substack{a_2}} \cdot \underbrace{(-i)}_{\substack{b_2}}\\
          \end{equation*}
        &= i = 2i^2-i+2i^2\\
        &= i^2=-1\\
        &= \sout{i}-\sout{i}-2-2\\
        &= -4
    \end{align*}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a full compilable code? Where does the `\Vect` (with an =uppercase V) come from? I had to remember `\sout` is defined in `ulem`…

Comment: In the LaTeX wiki, \sout was for crossing out, i need to cross the two "i". This is the code where LaTeX formats it wrong in the output. This is the exact Problem-Code. \vect is a vector. You can see from my handwriting post, how it has to begin. In the output, the order of the equation is a pure chaos and not how it has supposed to be.

Comment: i mean, you see the right order in the handwriting. obviously you see in the handwriting, i was running out of space, but you can still see the order

Comment: I could guess `Vect` was for a vector, but HOW is it defined? This is not standard LaTeX.

Comment: i am using sharelatex.com. and also in the wiki it says \vect{} for a vector

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_mathematischer_Symbole

Comment: the wiki you link to, says that vector is `\vec{}` not `\vect{}` nor `\Vec{}`. Be aware that the LaTeX commands are case sensitive.

Comment: as you can see, it still looks like how its supposed to be..and my latex says when i tip \v directly \Vec{}..so are you gonna to help me or not? I need help here and not some mimimimi advice. The syntax from a vector is correct, my problem is NOT the vector. Its the equation

Comment: it changes NOTHING if i write the V in v.

Comment: well first, temper a bit the attitude.  In order to be able to help you, we really need a compilable code as you have been asked in the first comment. We do not know which class or packages you are using. Also, we really don't want to have to rewrite your headers just to be able to compile your code.

Comment: I dont know how it is written for your latex. how should i know? i asked yesterday also a question, and 2 people were able to answer me, with my syntax. so how should i rewrite it? i learned with this syntax. so please tell me, how it is written "Right". or do you want my complete code? its a long long document.

Comment: i cant post my complete packages so i write multiple comments

Comment: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung

Comment: \usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools}

Comment: its a template i made for all my courses, so this is the reason why there are many packages i dont need with my math course document

Comment: This is why we ask for a minimum working example. Just enough to reproduce your problem. Look at the code that Bernard posted in his answer. You can take that code verbatim and compile it as a new document. this is what we mean by MWE.

Comment: okay, sorry, i didnt understand what you wanted from me and was guessing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility. It seems `\sout` won't work in math mode,a,d anyway, overstriking a formula when there's a minus sign will make it invisible. That's why I suggest to use the `\cancel` command, from the nomonymous package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \vec{a}
  &= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix*} \in \mathbb{C}^2\\
 \bar{\vec{a}}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] \bar{a}_1\\ \bar{a}_2 \end{pmatrix*}\\
 \vec{a}
 &= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 1-2i\\1+2i \end{pmatrix*}\\
 \bar{\vec{a}}&= \begin{pmatrix*} 1+2i\\1-2i \end{pmatrix*}\\
 (\bar{\vec{a}})^T &= (a+2i;1-2i)\\
\vec{b}&= \begin{pmatrix*}[r] i\\-i \end{pmatrix*}\\
 \langle\vec{a},\vec{b} \rangle &= (1+2i;1-2i) \cdot \begin{pmatrix*}[r] i\\-i \end{pmatrix*}\\
 &= (\underbrace{1+2i}_{a_1})\mkern-2mu\underbracket[0.6pt]{\vphantom{(}\mkern2mu i\mkern2mu}_{b_1}\mkern-2mu+\mathrlap{ \underbrace{(1-2i)}_{a_2} (\underbracket[0.6pt]{\vphantom{(}- i}_{b_2})} \\
 &= i + 2i^2-i+2i^2\\
 &= \cancel{ i-i }-2-2 & &( i^2=-1) \\
 &= -4
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does the mkern2mu, \mathrlap and \vphantom do? i dont know this

Comment: `\vphantom{(}`inserts  the height of its content (a parenthesis), here, so  the terms under the braces or under the brackets are all at the same vertical position. `\mathrlap` says to the compiler to consider its content has 0 width; I added it to have the explanation i² = -1 not too far from the computation on the left. \mkern 2mu` adds some mathematical kerning around `i` because the bracket would have too tight for my tast. `mu` is a length unit which is used only in math mode; its value is 1/18em (em is the width of M in the current font). For instance, a `thinspace` (`\,`) has length 3mu.

Comment: @Bernard -- although there are parentheses around the lst element "(-i)", they aren't included in the scope of the underbracket, so that's higher than the earlier one.  you still need the `\phantom`.

Comment: ah okay thanks :) now i know how i can use it in the future

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's right. I confess I didn't even check. I'll fix it in a moment. Thanks, milady!

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch: In general, we explain the code. Sometimes it would be quite long, and we wait \vphantom{(}r questions about it, if necessary. B.t.w., I fixed the flaw mentioned by Barbara Beeton.